# Redirect to homepage after countdown ends once

Tags: javascript, countdown, countdowntimer

I'm making a countdown timer in Javascript that redirects a visitor to another page when it ends. At the moment, I have a working version of countdown timer and redirection, however, redirection functions get triggered every second now and page keeps refreshing.

How can I make functions `homepage();` and `countdownPage();` run only once?

Thank you

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var countDownDate = new Date("July 11, 2019 09:00:00 GMT").getTime();


  function homepage() {
    location.replace("index.html");
  }

  function countdownPage() {
    location.replace("countdown.html");
  }

  var x = setInterval(function() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor(
      (distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)
    );
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML =
      days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    if (distance < 0) {
      clearInterval(x);
      document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Please refresh page";
      homepage();
    } else {
      countdownPage();
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: At the moment your code is calling `countdownPage()` whenever `distance` is greater than 0. Why do you want to redirect to a specific redirect page? Don't you want to stay on the page where this script is being executed?

Comment: I want every page on the website to redirect to countdown page while countdown is on and then disable redirection when countdown ends

Comment: But then it's okay, right? Someone enters the page => `distance >== 0` => redirect. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: when the countdown ends redirection function gets triggered every second, so page keeps refreshing every second without stopping. I need to make redirection function to run only once somehow